# Migrating a toolbar in a -.dot template file from Word 2003 to Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, templates, toolbar, microsoft-word-2003

I have been taking over the responsibility for development of a toolbar that was originally developed for Word 2003.
The toolbar resides in the file `MyTemplate.dot` (Word **2003**) and has been developed by many different people during the years.

When opening the file `MyTemplate.dot` in Word **2010** this is what I get:
[image: Toolbar in Word **2003**, directly migrated to Word **2010**]

**My problem:**
Now I would like to update the contents in the toolbar (add and remove buttons, connect new VBA macros to new buttons and so on). Normally, I would do this by using the tool "Custom UI Editor for Microsoft Office" (found [here](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2010/08/10/23248.aspx) (Updated version of the Custom UI Editor Tool), following a tutorial like [Customizing Context Menus in Office **2010**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee691832%28v=office.14%29.aspx)).

**What I have tried:**
When I try to open the file `MyTemplate.dot` (Word **2003**) with the Custom UI Editor Tool for Office **2010** this is what I get:

[image: Corrupted data!]

I am not sure if this is the right way to go when trying to update the contents in the toolbar?

I have also tried to affect the toolbar contents (`MyTemplate.dot`) from here: Word **2010** > File > Options > Customize Ribbon. This is what I get:

[image]

Customization options are grayed out?

**Facts:**

- There are no protections/locks/passwords in/on `MyTemplate.dot`. I
  can reach the VBA code without problems for example. I can save
  `MyTemplate.dot`, and update contents in it, but I cannot update the
  toolbar.

  I need to use the updated toolbar in Word **2010**.

**My question:** How should I edit the toolbar contents in `MyTemplate.dot` (originally developed in Word **2003**)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure if I reached the best solution. At least it works...

Here is my own conclusion:
There is no way a toolbar, developed in Word **2003**, residing in a Word **2003** `-.dot`-template file never ever could be edited from Word **2010**!

This is how I finally managed to do it:

1. Word **2003** > File > Open `MyTemplate.dot`
2. If the customized toolbar doesn't show up, make sure it has a corresponding check mark in Word **2003** > Tools > Customize - [Toolbars]
3. **Finally:** On the toolbar, right click the item you want to edit. This context menu will show up:
   [image: Edit toolbar context menu]

With help of this, you could edit pixels on toolbar buttons, update button text, remove and add buttons as you wish!